# Вычислить сумму ряда чисел

Tags: c#, циклы

Помогите пожалуйста вычислить сумму данного ряда. n - натурально число, x - действительное, вводятся пользователем. Нужно применять только циклы, встроенные функции (Pow) запрещенны. Конкретно возникла проблема с возведением k в степень k.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы всё просто.

```
private int K_In_Pow_K(int input_K)
{
    int result_pow_K = input_K;
    for (int i = 1; i < input_K; i++)
    {
        result_pow_K *= input_K;
    }
    return result_pow_K;
}
```

Вызов

```
int res = K_In_Pow_K(5); // результат 3125
```

Answer (score 0):

1. <s>У этого ряда сумма бесконечность и считать её бессмысленно.</s> Неправ, там ряд конечный.
2. k<sup>k</sup> рекуррентной формулой не считается, так что циклом.

Comment: А не могли бы помочь с циклом для k^k?

Comment: Неа, мне лень...